# ruby encode "\x\x" format to utf8 string or store in rails postgres db in current form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, utf-8, sha256, solidity

I created at `sha256` in a `solidity contract` and it returns

`"Y\xED\x90b\x82\xCDz\xCC\xD4\xA2\xD7\x9E\a\xBB\x13-'\xCC\xA2\x1F\x04Kv%!\xB6\xE8\xF8\xE9\xCB \x8B"`

Then when trying to save in `postgres` in a `string` data type field, I get

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::CharacterNotInRepertoire: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xed 0x90 0x62`

What is the best way to either **store as is** in `rails` and `postgres` or **convert** it to a `UTF8` string?

Comment: Are you sure this is a Ruby on Rails question?

Comment: I would try binary...

Comment: @amingilani If I can store the value in rails activerecord as it is, that would be great

Comment: @BradWerth that worked. can you create an answer and say change rails field data type to binary and then I'll mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this data should be stored in `binary` format.